# pipe and redirect do not work within docker run

Tags: docker

I'm trying to pipe a file to a application within a docker container and then redirect the app's output to a file, but it doesn't work with `docker run`:

```
cat path/file1 | docker run -i --name my-container my-image bash -c 'app > app.log'
```

The app is getting the file in **stdin** but it's output is not being redirected to app.log. Is there a way to do that?